# Using the Windows Phone 7 copy/paste functionality on my phone available on the emulator

Tags: windows-phone-7, sdk, emulation, copy-paste

Can I use the copy/paste functionality that I can find in the updated emulator (January 2011 dev tools update) on my phone?

Comment: Is this a new style to ask and answer own questions about copy/paste ?:D

Comment: As long as SO is a dev knowledge base, then why not?

Comment: nothing against, looks funny though (one by one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You cannot use it without the phone being updated.**

As of today, the official updated OS build that supports copy/paste is **not out yet**. Until you get that update and install it on the test device, you cannot use the new functionality on a phone with the older OS build, even though you can access it in the emulator.

Comment: so what happens if you side-load your new-functionality-app on your development phone that doesn't have the new OS build? it just ignores the new functionality or it kicks an error or you can't even load it or...?

Comment: It will run just like any other app - copy/paste is a system functionality (not app) tied to TextBox-like controls and if it's not available it simply won't be used.

Answer (score 0):

Just found this post:

[How to: Test Copy and Paste in Windows Phone Emulator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg588379%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Check also the official post and release notes:

http://create.msdn.com/en-US/news/Windows_Phone_Developer_Tools_January_2011_Update

Comment: Exactly what I stated in the post above - you cannot test the functionality on the phone itself (at the moment).